# Deleting a contact in Phonebook

Tags: samsung

While trying to delete a contact from my Samsung Galaxy phonebook, it tells me that it can't delete it since it as 'This contact contains info from multiple accounts. Information from read-only accounts will be hidden in your contacts list, not deleted'

What are they talking about and why can my decision to delete the contact not override this stupid message?

Comment: My guess is you have a messaging app like WhatsApp or Telegram installed that stores read-only data on that contact.

Answer (score 0):

Is it only that contact that shows that problem? If yes I suggest you call your network provider and ask them of the details of the number. If it proves abortive then you have to backup your contacts and hard reset the phone.